# Quiz game in tkinter- issue with classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a quiz game in Python tkinter and I'm using two classes in the program. In the `__init__` function of the `App` class, I'm defining four buttons. I'm using another class called `MyButton` to create the buttons. The issue is with calling the `MyButton` class inside of the `App` class. It throws the following error when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    class App:
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 21, in App
    def __init__(self, button1=MyButton(self, 50, 200, command=self.button1),
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

My code (I'm new to classes, so please don't make fun of me):

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import count


window = Tk()
window.title("Python Quiz")
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))


class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, kwargs, activebackground="lightblue")

        self.place(x=x, y=y)


class App:
    counter = count(0)
    def __init__(self, button1=Mybutton(self, 50, 200, command=self.button1),
                 button2 = MyButton(self, 150, 200, command=self.button2),
                 button3 = MyButton(self, 250, 200, command=self.button3),
                 button4 = MyButton(self, 350, 200, command=self.button4)):
        self.counter = next(self.counter)
        self.button1 = button1
        self.button2 = button2
        self.button3 = button3
        self.button4 = button4

        if self.counter > 5:
            return

    def questions(self):
        questions_list = ["What is the data type of the following object?: 3.5",
                          "What is a correct syntax to output \"Hello World\" in Python?",
                          "How do you insert COMMENTS in Python code?",
                          "Which one is NOT a legal variable name?",
                          "How do you create a variable with the NUMERIC value 5?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?"]

        answers = [["float", "int", "str", "bool"],
                   ["printf(\"Hello World\")", "print(Hello World)", "print(\"Hello World\")", "print\"(Hello)\""],
                   ["\\ COMMENT", "// COMMENT", "/* COMMENT */", "# COMMENT"],
                   ["MyVar", "my-var", "_myVar", "my_var"],
                   ["x == 5", "x = int(5)", "x = 5", "Options 2 and 3 are both correct"],
                   [955, 3692, -1, 105],
                   ["The sum is 6", "The sum is 4", "The sum is 5", "The sum is 22"],
                   ["True", "yes", "False", "no"],
                   ["100 97 180 99 101", "100 180 101", "97 99", "None of\nthe above"]]

        correct_answers = [0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0]

        question_num.configure("Question #%d" % self.counter)
        question_num.place(x=230, y=20)
        questions_label.configure(questions_list[self.counter - 1])
        self.button1.configure(text=answers[self.count - 1][0])
        self.button2.configure(text=answers[self.count - 1][1])
        self.button3.configure(text=answers[self.count - 1][2])
        self.button4.configure(text=answers[self.count - 1][3])

        if self.counter > 5:
            question_read = open("question%d.txt" % self.counter, "r")
            code_label.configure(text=question_read.readlines())
            code_label.place(x=230, y=100)
            question_read.close()

        return correct_answers[self.counter - 1]


def start_command():
    destroy_list = [welcome, quit_button]

    for i in destroy_list:
        i.destroy()

    destroy_start()


def destroy_start():
    start_button.destroy()
    call = App()
    call.questions()


welcome = Label(window, text="Welcome the Python Quiz!", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50))
welcome.place(x=230, y=20)

start_button = Button(window, text="START", bg="lime", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50), width=7,
                              command=start_command)
start_button.place(x=470, y=220)

quit_button = Button(window, text="QUIT", bg="red", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50), width=7,
                             command=lambda: quit())
quit_button.place(x=470, y=370)
question_label = Label(window, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30))
question_num = Label(window)
code_label = Label(window)


window.mainloop()
```

The content of the text files used in the program:

question6.txt:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
    print(num1)
  elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
    print(num2)
  else:
    print(num3)

max_num(3692,955,105)
```

question7.txt:

```
def count_digit (num):
    sum= 0
    while num>=1:
         sum=sum+num%10
         num=num//10
    print("The sum is: " + str(sum))

count_digit(63625)
```

question 8.txt:

```
def is_there_char (str):
    if str.find("!") == -1:
        print("no")
    else:
        print("yes")

is_there_char("pink")
```

question9.txt:

```
my_dict = {
  "32233344": 100,
  "08098509": 97,
  "22222299": 180,
  "23563346" : 99,
  "22224444" : 101
}
for key in my_dict:
    if my_dict [key] >90:
        print(my_dict[key])
```

Please help me fix this issue

Comment: I think you should look at a object oriented programming tutorial (that focuses on python).

Comment: I've watched a few tutorials, I just need help with this particular issue and the tutorials didn't help me fix it

Comment: You're trying to reference an attribute of the instance (`self`) before it's even been created — which is one of the main things that happens *inside* the `__init__()` method. As @TheLizzard mentioned, I think you need to get a better grasp of OOP (in Python). Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: So how can I do it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in there. In the error it displays `Mybutton` but your function is called `MyButton`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. But I have a new error now:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    class App:
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 21, in App
    def __init__(self, button1=MyButton(self, 50, 200, command=self.button1),
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: python IS case sensitive, actually most programming languages nowadays are case-sensitive, that is kinda the most basic things, also for such minor things (and I think typos in particular) you should either answer it in comments (which you can't) or raise a flag (not sure if you can do that but in case you can, I think the flag "... or was caused by typos" is the appropriate one)

Comment: Is there in Buttons the Argument self allowed? Or it could be because you defined it in the same step